# html post form different destinations

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, http-post

I am developing a django web app in which I would like to have a registration process. In this  registration process I have of course a form asking for name, email and password. What I would like to do is, send the form via post to 2 different places. One of which is of course the registration database which saves the password and the like, and the other being the Emencia newsletter app. In the case it helps, Emencia only needs email and a name (optional).

So how can I do this with only one form, 2 places to send it to and, taking just some of the data of the form and not all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that the better approach is to handle this on the server side, let me correct that it is very **possible** to submit the same form to different server side scripts.

See the page below for the script and some demos:
[How to create a multi-submit form](http://www.html-form-guide.com/web-form/submit-form-multiple-scripts.html)

It works in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no way to send a form to two ressources.

What you CAN do is send a HTTP request in your register script to the newsletter script, e.g. using urllib2.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would have to use Javascript & AJAX

http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with jQuery...

```
$("input:submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // javascript validation

    // run this if validation succeeds
    $.ajax({
        url: "url to emencia newsletter",
        type: 'post',
        data: "Email=" + $("#emailField").val() + "&Name=" + $("#nameField").val(),
        success: function(result) {
            // do stuff
            $('form').submit();
        }
    });
    // could also go here if you don't want the success callback -- $('form').submit();
});
```

So what happens is you click your submit button.  The e.preventDefault tells the browser to stop the form from submitting.  You then run an ajax request to submit to emencia.  On success it submits the original form.  I am not sure if you need to put the form submit in the success or simply place it after the ajax request. I don't think it really matters.

Comment: Could you ellaborate further... for example does the success: part has to exist in this case I just want it to be transparent in the case of success just redirect towards the registration complete site. Also where on the form should I call the script? onsubmit or something like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of trickery used to work in most browsers but...it seems that it only works in Firefox now.  Adding a delay between the two submits makes it work in IE but not Chrome.  I'm actually amazed it still works in firefox :)

```
<html>
<body>
<form method='post' action='place1.php' onsubmit='this.action="place1.php";this.submit();this.action="place2.php";this.submit();return false;'>
<input type='text' name='thing' value='something' />
<input type='submit' value='send' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```